# Trying to use SendGrid with Angular and Node

Tags: node.js, angular, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Using Angular and SendGrid, I am trying to send an email. I installed the NPM package correctly but am having issues with implementing the code. I generated an API key and stored it in the directory with

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

The Typescript is:

```
sgemail(){
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail'); //ERROR: Cannot find name 'require'.
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY); //ERROR: Cannot find name 'process'.
  const msg = {
    to: 'test@example.com',
    from: 'test@example.com',
    subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
  };
  console.log(msg);
  sgMail.send(msg);
}
```

I am firing this on a button click.

Sendgrid has no information on their site about importing packages like how you have to use `import { Vibration } from '@ionic-native/vibration';` to use Ionic's vibration package.

Answer (score 2):

You could try sending a POST request manually using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to their [Send Mail API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html). And don't forget the [Authorization Headers](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html). Below is a same untested JavaScript code snippet to try. Fill in YOUR_API_KEY and update the to email to one of your emails.

```
  var payload = {
    "personalizations": [
      {
        "to": [
          {
            "email": "john@example.com"
          }
        ],
        "subject": "Hello, World!"
      }
    ],
    "from": {
      "email": "from_address@example.com"
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text/plain",
        "value": "Hello, World!"
      }
    ]
  };
  var myHeaders = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_API_KEY",
  });
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );
  fetch("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
  {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: data
  })
  .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
  .then(function(data){ console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.