# Send mail in an angular 15 app through sendgrid in a safe way

Tags: angular, email, sendgrid, angular15

What is the best strategy to send a mail through an angular app?
I have choosen sendgrid with free plan (100mail/hour) which allows you to send a mail through their API with an API key and their package: [@sendgrid/mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail).

Doing a direct service API call result in a CORS error:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878739/trying-to-use-sendgrid-with-angular-and-node)

While using the mail service directly in angular app seems a not recommened way of doing it because you're at risk of exposing your API key to external malicious actors.

What I tought of is to, along the angular app, run a small express.js server that acts as a bridge between my angular app and sendgrid API so it doesn't expose the API key.

But I'm wondering if there is any common practice or best practice to do this that I am not aware of.

I won't post the code of my angular app here as it's the most common angular app:
A reactive form that sends a mail through a send button.

I just need to get a picture on how to do this. The code samples for sendgrid can be gound in the package, but for node.js and not angular.

Thanks

Comment: what you said looks ok to me, create a backend service that acts as a proxy between your Angular app and the SendGrid API as you said thats better than doing everything on frontend and leaking your key

Comment: @RachidO How one would protect this bridge service from malicious actors?
A CORS policy?
A malicious actor would be able to see in the browser dev tools the requests made to this bridge service, intercept the url and use it to send mails?